# Cчитывание Stdin без ожидания символа разделителя (\n)

Tags: rust

**Требуется:** считать данные с stdin без ожидания символа разделителя "\n". В расте stdin были найдены лишь функции считывания пока не произойдет поступление "\n" (нажатия enter), а требуется поступление конкретно 1 символа  без ожидания "\n".

**Пример:**

```
use std::io::Read;

fn main() {
    let stdin = ::std::io::stdin();
    let mut handle = stdin.lock();

    let mut array_read = [0u8];
    loop {
        println!("Key:");


        if let Err(e) = handle.read_exact(&mut array_read) {
            panic!("I can not lock stdin. {:?}", e);
        }
        match array_read[0] {
            b'r' | b'R' => {
                println!("R");
            },
            b'c' | b'C' => {
                println!("C");
            },
            _ => {},
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Для POSIX-совместимых OS, есть крейт [termios](https://crates.io/crates/termios).